# Construct absolute filename from a filename and a directory name

Tags: perl, path, directory, filepath

I have two values:

- a current directory name
- an absolute or relative file name

I need to construct an unambiguous absolute filename (starting with / and without any ../ and without ./) which corresponds to accessing this file while the directory is the current directory.

I need to do this in Perl in Unix.

I've tried `use File::Path;` but this does not work right (bug?):

```
perl -MPath::Class -e 'my $fileObj = Path::Class::File->new("/boot", "/xx"); 
                       print $fileObj->absolute, "\n";'
```

Output:

```
/boot/xx
```

But it should print `/xx` because it is an absolute path, and it should not depend on the current directory!

Comment: You code is using `Path::Class` and `Path::Class::File`, yet you say you're using `File::Path`…that's a bit confusing. [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3A%3AClass) does document itself as a layer atop `File::Path`, though.  I think your problem is GIGO: Garbage In, Garbage Out.  The file name should not contain a slash; when it does, you get what you get.  The file name is created by prepending the list of directory names (one in your example) to the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# ("/base/path", "x") -> "/base/path/x"
# ("/base/path", "../x") -> "/base/x"
# ("/base/path", "/x") -> "/x"
sub AbsoluteNormalizedPath {
  my ($dir, $filename) = @_;
  $filename = "$dir/$filename" unless $filename =~ m{^/};
  my @components = split m{/+}, $filename;
  shift @components; # Первый компонент всегда - пустая строка, вырезаем его
  # Компоненты без ".." и ".". Работает как стек: добавляем обычные компоненты, убираем последние компонент на "..", игнорируем ".":
  my @normalizedComponents;
  foreach my $component (@components) {
    next if $component eq '.';
    if($component eq '..') {
      # В Unix parent директория корневой директории - сама корневая директория, то есть /.. - то же самое, что /
      # Так что, если список пустой - это не ошибка, оставляем его пустым (что соответсвует корневой директории).
      pop @normalizedComponents if @normalizedComponents;
    } else {
      push @normalizedComponents, $component;
    }
  }
  return '/' . join('/', @normalizedComponents);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Path::Class` use the whole path to determine if a file is absolute or relative so in the example it is: "/boot/xx". the outputted string. To solve your problem you need something like this:

```
use Path::Class

my $fileObj = Path::Class::File->new("/xx");

$fileObj = Path::Class::File->new("/boot",$fileObj->relative()) if $fileObj->is_relative();
```

Comment: What do you mean? $fileObj->absolute is the absolute path to the file without ../.